# How to develop and test HealthBOT locally

Tags: botframework, microsoft-health-bot

we are using Microsoft HealthBOT and there is a really cool online editor that Microsoft has provided.

We want to integrate the bot into a div of our own choice, one that is themed accordingly. Microsoft supports that and they have provided a GIT repo that generates the container.

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/
```

The problem is that they recommend deploying this to Azure and setting the secrets and one of the files i.e. server.js from above will read the secret from my environment in Azure.

The issue with this is that we cannot do any local development in the context of theming.

I tried to clone the GIT repo, that works, but how to supply a local install of this repo the Azure environment keys?

Any help in this direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for local development and testing a UI. You can use the [Microsoft Botframework Webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). I already use this webchat for my MS Healthbots. While this can be useful for running your bot like end user. You will continue to work your development on the MS Healthbot portal.

Please let me know if this answer help you :)

Best regard!